# prevent/secure database entires from users

Tags: php, sql

I am new to sql how do i make this code more secure from sql injection and over wrong doing.

```
// Variables 
$db_host = 'localhost'; 
$db_user = 'user'; 
$db_pass = 'pass'; 
$db_name = 'db'; 

$Username = $_POST['username']; 
$Email    = $_POST['email'];     

// DB Connect
$connect = mysql_connect( $db_host, $db_user, $db_pass ) or die( mysql_error() ); 
$connection = $connect; 

mysql_select_db( $db_name, $connect ) or die( mysql_error() ); 

// Inserting into DB 
$qInsertUser = mysql_query(" INSERT INTO `database` (`id`, `username`, `email`) VALUES ( ``, `$Username`, `$Email`) "); 

if ($qInsertUser){ 
    echo "You are now subscribed to our newsletter. Thank you!"; 
} else { 
    echo "Error!"; 
}
```

Comment: you can use real_escape_string.That will be safe to more extend.

Comment: -1: There are a **ton** of articles on this as a result of a single Google search.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php). Instead of:

```
$qInsertUser = mysql_query(" INSERT INTO `database` (`id`, `username`, `email`) VALUES ( ``, `$Username`, `$Email`) ");
```

Replace it with a prepared statement and execution:

```
$sth = $dbh->prepare('INSERT INTO `database` (`id`, `username`, `email`) VALUES (?, ?, ?)');
$sth->execute(array($id, $username, $email));
```

Let the libraries handle all the quoting for you.

Comment: +1 for PDO, prepared statements are the way to go.
Also, don't forget named parameters

Comment: @jcinacio, indeed, named parameters are well worth the slight amount of extra work, but when I used to give named parameters as examples, I got feedback that the examples looked like enough work that people would be needlessly scared off. For _this_ query, I probably wouldn't bother, but three parameters is definitely about time to consider just writing the named version in the first place. :)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are [escaping](http://us.php.net/mysql_real_escape_string) the values. Rather than:

```
$Username = $_POST['username']; 
$Email    = $_POST['email'];
```

try this:

```
$Username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
$Email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
```

Please note that this answer is by no means meant to be an exhaustive anti-SQL-injection resource, but hopefully it will get you going on the right track.

Answer (score 0):

Beside mysql_real_escape_string,   also try to validate the input.  users shouldn't be allowed to enter whatever.   use regexp syntax and type casting or settype.   this I mean on server side in php. javascript validations are not enough I've seen many programmers and webmasters spend more energy on js validation while in php they write no validation at all.